# HTML/CSS change color of buttons including other buttons when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

```js
var level1 = document.getElementsById("bar1");
var level2 = document.getElementsById("bar2");
var level3 = document.getElementsById("bar3");
var level4 = document.getElementsById("bar4");
var level5 = document.getElementsById("bar5");

function changeColor1(){
  level1.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
  level2.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';
  level3.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';
  level4.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';
  level5.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';
}

function changeColor2(){
  level1.style.backgroundColor = red;
  level2.style.backgroundColor = red;
  level3.style.backgroundColor = none;
  level4.style.backgroundColor = none;
  level5.style.backgroundColor = none;
}

function changeColor3(){
  level1.style.backgroundColor = red;
  level2.style.backgroundColor = red;
  level3.style.backgroundColor = red;
  level4.style.backgroundColor = none;
  level5.style.backgroundColor = none;
}

function changeColor4(){
  level1.style.backgroundColor = red;
  level2.style.backgroundColor = red;
  level3.style.backgroundColor = red;
  level4.style.backgroundColor = red;
  level5.style.backgroundColor = none;
}

function changeColor5(){
  level1.style.backgroundColor = red;
  level2.style.backgroundColor = red;
  level3.style.backgroundColor = red;
  level4.style.backgroundColor = red;
  level5.style.backgroundColor = red;
}
```

```css
button {
    background-color: white;
    border: 0.5px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 4px 24px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cat Dominates World</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h3>Cat Dominates World</h3>
    <header>

    <button id="bar1" onClick="changeColor1()"></button>
    <button id="bar2" onClick="changeColor2()"></button>
    <button id="bar3" onClick="changeColor3()"></button>
    <button id="bar4" onClick="changeColor4()"></button>
    <button id="bar5" onClick="changeColor5()"></button>

</body>
</html>
```

Hello! I'm making 5 level bar using HTML/CSS now, and trying to change the color of multiple buttons. For example, clicking third button, the color of 1st/2nd/3rd buttons change to red. It doesn't work with the code above though.
Can you give me the solution for the problem?

Comment: typo, remove s from getlementsbyid

Comment: You should always check console for any error. Its **document.getElementById** not **document.getElementsById**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `document.getElementById` not `document.getElementsById`. Also your colors are never defined.

```js
const level1 = document.getElementById("bar1"); // correct funtion
const level2 = document.getElementById("bar2");
const level3 = document.getElementById("bar3");
const level4 = document.getElementById("bar4");
const level5 = document.getElementById("bar5");

const red = "#FF0000"; // define the colors
const none = '#FFFFFF';

function changeColor1(){
  level1.style.backgroundColor = red;
  level2.style.backgroundColor = none;
  level3.style.backgroundColor = none;
  level4.style.backgroundColor = none;
  level5.style.backgroundColor = none;
}

function changeColor2(){
  level1.style.backgroundColor = red;
  level2.style.backgroundColor = red;
  level3.style.backgroundColor = none;
  level4.style.backgroundColor = none;
  level5.style.backgroundColor = none;
}

function changeColor3(){
  level1.style.backgroundColor = red;
  level2.style.backgroundColor = red;
  level3.style.backgroundColor = red;
  level4.style.backgroundColor = none;
  level5.style.backgroundColor = none;
}

function changeColor4(){
  level1.style.backgroundColor = red;
  level2.style.backgroundColor = red;
  level3.style.backgroundColor = red;
  level4.style.backgroundColor = red;
  level5.style.backgroundColor = none;
}

function changeColor5(){
  level1.style.backgroundColor = red;
  level2.style.backgroundColor = red;
  level3.style.backgroundColor = red;
  level4.style.backgroundColor = red;
  level5.style.backgroundColor = red;
}
```

```css
button {
    background-color: white;
    border: 0.5px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 4px 24px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cat Dominates World</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h3>Cat Dominates World</h3>
    <header>

    <button id="bar1" onClick="changeColor1()"></button>
    <button id="bar2" onClick="changeColor2()"></button>
    <button id="bar3" onClick="changeColor3()"></button>
    <button id="bar4" onClick="changeColor4()"></button>
    <button id="bar5" onClick="changeColor5()"></button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you can get a reference to an HTML element using the `document.getElementById()` function. In your script you've called it getElement**s**ById().

Furthermore the variable **red** ain't defined anywhere so it obviously can't change the color to red.
Try adding

```
var red='#FFFFFF';
```

Lastly to reset a color you can't assign **none** to the `backgroundColor` property - it has to be **null**.

Answer (score 0):

**Its minified and working  use this snippet**

```js
function changeColor1() {
  document.getElementById("bar1").style.background = "red";
  document.getElementById("bar2").style.background = "none";
  document.getElementById("bar3").style.background = "none";
  document.getElementById("bar4").style.background = "none";
  document.getElementById("bar5").style.background = "none";
}function changeColor2() {
  document.getElementById("bar1").style.background = "red";
  document.getElementById("bar2").style.background = "red";
  document.getElementById("bar3").style.background = "none";
  document.getElementById("bar4").style.background = "none";
  document.getElementById("bar5").style.background = "none";
}function changeColor3() {
  document.getElementById("bar1").style.background = "red";
  document.getElementById("bar2").style.background = "red";
  document.getElementById("bar3").style.background = "red";
  document.getElementById("bar4").style.background = "none";
  document.getElementById("bar5").style.background = "none";
}function changeColor4() {
  document.getElementById("bar1").style.background = "red";
  document.getElementById("bar2").style.background = "red";
  document.getElementById("bar3").style.background = "red";
  document.getElementById("bar4").style.background = "red";
  document.getElementById("bar5").style.background = "none";
}function changeColor5() {
  document.getElementById("bar1").style.background = "red";
  document.getElementById("bar2").style.background = "red";
  document.getElementById("bar3").style.background = "red";
  document.getElementById("bar4").style.background = "red";
  document.getElementById("bar5").style.background = "red";
}
```

```css
button {
    background-color: white;
    border: 0.5px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 4px 24px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cat Dominates World</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h3>Cat Dominates World</h3>
    <header>

    <button id="bar1" onClick="changeColor1()"></button>
    <button id="bar2" onClick="changeColor2()"></button>
    <button id="bar3" onClick="changeColor3()"></button>
    <button id="bar4" onClick="changeColor4()"></button>
    <button id="bar5" onClick="changeColor5()"></button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this has already been answered, there is a much better way to factor this code, to allow it to behave in a much more maintainable, and dynamic way.

Have a look at the following commented code:

```js
// Grab all the buttons contained within the awesome-btn-group.
// This makes it easier to work with it later, and avoids searching the DOM excessively for a button.
let levels = document.getElementById("awesome-btn-group").getElementsByTagName("BUTTON");

// Define as many colors as you want inside this JS object.
let uiColors = {
  red: "#FF0000",
  white: "#FFFFFF",
};

// Add event listeners to each button in the awesome-btn-group.
for (let level of levels) {
  level.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    // When a click event is triggered on one of the buttons, run the updateButtonColors
    // function, passing which button has been clicked to that function.
    updateButtonColors(event.target)
  });
}

// Handles the click event that's fired whenever one of the button elements in the 
// awesome-btn-group div is clicked.
function updateButtonColors(button) {

  // A variable to store whether or not the maximum level has been reached in the following loop.
  let isMaxLevelReached = false;
  
  // Loop through each button.
  for (let level of levels) {

    // If the maximum level HASN'T been reached yet, turn the button red.
    if (!isMaxLevelReached) {
      level.style.backgroundColor = uiColors.red;
    }
    
    // Otherwise, if the maximum level HAS been reached, turn the button white.
    else {
      level.style.backgroundColor = uiColors.white;
    }
    
    // Check to see if the button that's been clicked is the button that's currently being looped over.
    // If it is, we know that the maximum level has been reached, and therefore on further iterations
    // of the loop, we can turn the remaining buttons white.
    if (level === button) {
    
      // Leaving off the keyword "let" here, so to simply update the value stored in it, rather than creating
      // a new, locally scoped isMaxLevelReached variable.
      isMaxLevelReached = true;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
button {
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 8px;
  width: 48px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h3>Cat Dominates World</h3>
</header>

<div id="awesome-btn-group">
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
</div>
```

As you can see, the number of button elements can be altered, without requiring any changes being made to the JavaScript code.

Also, the colors are now pulling in from an object (a special type of variable), so, similarly to CSS, you can change the color hex once, and it will propagate, and just work, everywhere else that it's referenced within your JavaScript.